# Conditions after if statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I need a method that takes two arguments: the number of donuts and a maximum donut intake. This method should return `good job` if he eats less than half his maximum intake and `to get back on his diet` when it exceeds his maximum. I am having trouble with the syntax. I tried the following but cannot pass the rspec:

```
def some_donuts(donuts, maximum)
  if donuts < maximum
    "Get back on your diet!"
  else donuts > (maximum / 2)
    "Good job!"
  end
end
```

Can anyone help with some hints in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

`else` doesn't accept a condition. In fact, `else` should contain the code to be executed when the `if` clause doesn't match.

```
if first > second
  # do something
else
  # first =< second
end
```

If you need more than one condition, use `elsif`.

```
if first > second
  # do something
elsif first == second
  # do something
else
  # first < second
end
```

In your case

```
def some_donuts(donuts, maximum)
  if donuts < maximum
    "Get back on your diet!"
  elsif donuts > (maximum / 2)
    "Good job!"
  end
end
```

Please note that your `if` statement is missing an `else`. What should happen when `donuts =< maximum/2`?